# Basics of Normalizing Cross-Correlation with a View to Comparing Signals

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, python, cross-correlation, normalization

I'm trying to understand how cross-correlation is used determine the similarity of two signals. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO8s1TrElEw&t=463s) offers a very clear explanation of the basics, but I still don't understand how to use normalization effectively to prevent strong signals from dominating the cross-correlation measure when you have signals with different energy levels. The same tutor, David Dorran, discusses the issue of normalization [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngEC3sXeUb4), and explains how to normalize the correlation using the dot product, but I still have some questions.

I wrote this python routine to do cross-correlations between every pair of signals from a group of signals:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mycorrelate2d(df, normalized=False):
    # initialize cross correlation matrix with zeros
    ccm = np.zeros(shape=df.shape, dtype=list)
    for i, row_dict1 in enumerate(
                        df.to_dict(orient='records')):
        outer_row = list(row_dict1.values())    
        for j, row_dict2 in enumerate(
                            df.to_dict(orient='records')):
            inner_row = list(row_dict2.values())   
            x = np.correlate(inner_row, outer_row)
            if normalized:
                n = np.dot(inner_row, outer_row)                
                x = x / n
            ccm[i][j] = x
    return ccm
```

Suppose I have 3 signals of increasing magnitude:
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] and [7, 8, 9]

I want to cross-correlate these three signals to see which pairs are similar, but when I pass these 3 signals into the routine I wrote, I don't appear to get a measure of similarity. The size of the cross correlation values is just a function of the energy signal. Period. Even the cross correlation of a signal ***with itself*** yields lower values than the cross correlation of that same signal with another signal of higher energy.

```
df_x3 = pd.DataFrame(
        np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
                  [4, 5, 6], 
                  [7, 8, 9]]).reshape(3, -1))
mycorrelate2d(df_x3)
```

This yields:

```
array([[array([ 3,  8, 14,  8,  3]), 
        array([12, 23, 32, 17,  6]),
        array([21, 38, 50, 26,  9])],
       [array([ 6, 17, 32, 23, 12]), 
        array([24, 50, 77, 50, 24]),
        array([ 42,  83, 122,  77,  36])],
       [array([ 9, 26, 50, 38, 21]), 
        array([ 36,  77, 122,  83,  42]),
        array([ 63, 128, 194, 128,  63])]], dtype=object)
```

Now, I pass in the same 3 signals, but this time I indicate that I want normalized results:

```
mycorrelate2d(df_x3, normalized=True)
```

This yields:

```
array([[array([ 0.2142, 0.5714,  1., 0.5714, 0.2142]),
        array([ 0.375,  0.71875, 1., 0.5312, 0.1875]),
        array([ 0.42,   0.76,    1., 0.52,   0.18])],
       [array([ 0.1875, 0.5312,  1., 0.7187, 0.375]),
        array([ 0.3116, 0.6493,  1., 0.6493, 0.3116]),
        array([ 0.3442, 0.6803,  1., 0.6311, 0.2950])],
       [array([ 0.18,   0.52,    1., 0.76,   0.42]),
        array([ 0.2950, 0.6311,  1., 0.6803, 0.3442]),
        array([ 0.3247, 0.6597,  1., 0.6597, 0.3247])]],
        dtype=object)
```

All the max values are now 1!! So we went from having max values that were based on spurious differences to having no difference between the max values at all! I readily confess that I do not understand how cross-correlation is used to detect similarity between signals. What is the analytical work flow of someone comparing signals with cross-correlation?

Comment: Would a [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) suit your needs? I.e., a single number $\in[-1,1]$ for each pair of signals.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions! I was thinking of building a cross-correlation matrix with a value for each pair of signals. I suppose Pearson is fine, but in the Wikipedia article you linked to they mention the "Intraclass" correlation coefficient which sounds a lot like what I need to do, because I have a group of signals that varying in tandem, except when there is some kind of interference, so I want to detect when and how many signals are diverging from the general pattern.

Comment: I think the correlation coefficient solves the problem of normalization, but it might be worth describing in more detail in your question what exactly it is that you want to achieve. Right now I can't say if intraclass correlation would be a good candidate or not.